# Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType1`2 [System.Int64,System.String]' to type 'ConsoleApplication1.Profile'.

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I very new to Linq and Entity frame work, i have problem with my below code. I am getting error

> Unable to cast object of type  '<>f__AnonymousType1`2
>   [System.Int64,System.String]' to type 'ConsoleApplication1.Profile'

.

My Code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProfileEntitiesContext obj = new ProfileEntitiesContext();
            List<Profile> list = new List<Profile>();
            var test = (from c in obj.Customer
                       join a in obj.Address
                       on c.ProfileId
                       equals a.Customer.ProfileId 
                       select new
                       {
                           CustomerProfileId = c.CustomerProfileId,
                           FirstName = c.FirstName
                   AddressLine1 = a.Line1   
                       }).ToList().Cast<CustomerConfidentialProfile>();

foreach(var cust in test) // Unable to cast object of type  '<>f__AnonymousType1`2
//[System.Int64,System.String]' to type 'ConsoleApplication1.Profile'.
            {
                list.Add(cust);
            }
        }

public class Profile
    {
        int _CustomerProfileId;
        string _FirstName;
        string _AddressLine1;


        public int CustomerProfileId
        {
            get { return _CustomerProfileId; }
            set { _CustomerProfileId = value; }
        }


        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _FirstName; }
            set { _FirstName = value; }
        }

  public string AddressLine1
        {
            get { return _AddressLine1; }
            set { _AddressLine1= value; }
        }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that from the LINQ-query you are returning a anonymous type ( by using the `new { ... }` syntax.

However, you try to jam this object into a `List<Profile>`. So it's complaining that you are trying to put this anonymous object into a List that only takes `Profile` objects.

Why just not replace `new { ...` with `new Profile { ...` since you are using the same fields in the anonymous type as you do in the Profile type.

And remove `ToList` and `Cast` at the end as well.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to put anonymous object into the List for the above sample.

Comment: You can't, short of using a weak list like ArrayList. See my edit on how to fix your code so you can use the strongly typed list as you do now.

Comment: OMG! You saved me a half day of struggling. The problem was an anonymous object.

Answer (score 4):

Thats because the anonymous type `<>f__AnonymousType1'2 [System.Int64,System.String]` IS NOT Profile! (not an instance and not an instance of ancestor). Try to replace your select like this:

```
select new CustomerConfidentialProfile
{
CustomerProfileId = c.CustomerProfileId,
FirstName = c.FirstName,
AddressLine1 = a.Line1,
property assignments go futher   
})
```

Comment: Haha, googled forever and this one clued me to what I needed to do. I joined 2 tables in LINQ and only wanted one column from the 2nd table..Figured I should make a class with the columns I wanted, but couldn't load it in the controller and foreach it in the view until I read this and did exactly the same for my columns in my new class. Got my vote. I love StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast an anonymous type to a named type. But you can construct a named type directly:

```
select new CustomerConfidentialProfile()
                   {
                       CustomerProfileId = c.CustomerProfileId,
                       FirstName = c.FirstName
               AddressLine1 = a.Line1   
                   }).ToList();
```